# Contract mints token id 0 ERC721A

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, nft, erc-721

My contract mints token id #0 instead of #1.

I found out it has to do with the _safemint function but i can't seem to get it fixed

How can i make the first mint token id #1?

```
   function _safeMint(
    address to,
    uint256 quantity,
    bytes memory _data
) internal virtual {
    _mint(to, quantity);

    unchecked {
        if (to.code.length != 0) {
            uint256 end = _currentIndex;
            uint256 index = end - quantity;
            do {
                if (!_checkContractOnERC721Received(address(0), to, index++, _data)) {
                    revert TransferToNonERC721ReceiverImplementer();
                }
            } while (index < end);
            // Reentrancy protection.
            if (_currentIndex != end) revert();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @dev Equivalent to `_safeMint(to, quantity, '')`.
 */
function _safeMint(address to, uint256 quantity) internal virtual {
    _safeMint(to, quantity, '');
}




   function mint(uint256 numberOfTokens) external payable
{
require(isPublicSaleActive, "Public sale is paused.");
require(totalSupply() + numberOfTokens < maxSupply + 1, "Maximum supply exceeded.");

require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_MINTS_PER_TX, "Maximum mints per transaction exceeded.");

if(freeNFTAlreadyMinted + numberOfTokens > NUM_FREE_MINTS)
{
    require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * numberOfTokens <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 1");
} 
else 
{
    uint sender_balance = balanceOf(msg.sender);
    
    if (sender_balance + numberOfTokens > MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET) 
    { 
        if (sender_balance < MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET)
        {
            uint free_available = MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET - sender_balance;
            uint to_be_paid = numberOfTokens - free_available;
            require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * to_be_paid <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 2");

            freeNFTAlreadyMinted += free_available;
        }
        else
        {
            require(PUBLIC_SALE_PRICE * numberOfTokens <= msg.value, "Invalid ETH value sent. Error Code: 3");
        }
    }  
    else 
    {
        require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_FREE_PER_WALLET, "Maximum mints per transaction exceeded");
        freeNFTAlreadyMinted += numberOfTokens;
    }
}

_safeMint(msg.sender, numberOfTokens);

 }
```

Comment: Can you please show the`_safeMint()` code

Comment: Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFTs always go from 0 and then usually to 9999. Take BAYC for example: https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d/0

But if you wish to start with id = 1, then theres a function in ERC721A, that sets the starting id:

```
function _startTokenId() internal view virtual returns (uint256) {
   return 0;
}
```

You can override the function in your contract and set it to 1. Just add this to your contract:

```
function _startTokenId() internal view override returns (uint256) {
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an NFT expert but the tokenIds is an array and an array aways start with index 0. In mine NFT projects i always deploying the tokenId to the deployers address, this tokenURI usually pointed to some general art related to the project.

Answer (score 0):

_safeMint generally mint the tokenId supplied to the function

```
_safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId)
```

Here is a working example with ERC721 smart contract

```
Counters.Counter private _tokenIdTracker;
........
function _mintMultiple(uint256 numberOfTokens) private {
   for(uint256 i; i < numberOfTokens; i++){
       _tokenIdTracker.increment();
       uint256 newTokenID = _tokenIdTracker.current();
       _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention i got a erc721a contract, thanks for helping out though !

Comment: `safeMint` method is fine, the issue seems to be in `_mint(to, quantity)` method